# How to expand sharepoint 2010 calendar by default

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

When i use the code below to expand calendar by default.
It breaks the ribbon when i click items or list from the ribbon to edit a list.
It starts showing loading.... and doesn't stop.

Cheers

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('WaitForCalendarToLoad');

function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {

    if (typeof SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a == 'undefined') {
        // post SP1
        var pwold$4b = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function () {
            pwold$4b();
            ColourCalendar();
        }
    }
    else {
        // pre SP1
        var pwold$4a = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;
        SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function () {
            pwold$4a();
            ColourCalendar();
        }
    }
} 
function ColourCalendar() {     
    SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarInstanceRepository.firstInstance().expandAll();   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add a content editor web part on the Calendar view of the Calendar list .
2. Add the code below in the HTML source of the content editor web part .

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">     
   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('WaitForCalendarToLoad');

   function WaitForCalendarToLoad() {  
       var old$4a = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a;

       SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4a = function () {
           old$4a();

           ctrl = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarInstanceRepository.firstInstance();

           if (ctrl) {
               ctrl.expandAll();
           }
       }
   }
   </script>
   ```
3. Save the changes and all the events on the Calendar view is expanded by default with a ‘collapse ‘ choice under the events .

Original post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a24da49a-7fc8-47c6-a125-95e4a5b2d095/sharepoint-2010-calendar-expand-all?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but here is the solution (from [my blog](http://blog.kodono.info/wordpress/2014/12/18/how-to-expand-sharepoint-2010-calendar-by-default-javascript/)):

```
// the below function simulate a click on a link
function fireEventClick(elem){
    if(document.createEvent){                                                
      var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initMouseEvent('click', /* Event type */
      true, /* Can bubble */
      true, /* Cancelable */
      document.defaultView, /* View */
      1, /* Mouse clicks */
      0, /* Screen x */
      0, /* Screen y */
      0, /* Client x */
      0, /* Client y */
      false, /* Ctrl */
      false, /* Alt */
      false, /* Shift */
      false, /* Meta */
      0, /* Button */
      null); /* Related target */
      elem.dispatchEvent(e);                    
    } else { // pour IE
      elem.click();
    }
}

// wait for all the events to be loaded
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('changeCalendarEventLinkIntercept');
function changeCalendarEventLinkIntercept() {
  var OldCalendarNotify4a = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b;
  SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarNotify.$4b = function () {
    OldCalendarNotify4a();
    // here all the events are loaded so we can expand them
    setTimeout(function() {
      ExpandEvents(0)
    }, 250)
  }
}

// Expand the events
// because Sharepoint redraw ALL the events when we click on Expand,
// then we need a special recurrent function
function ExpandEvents(idx) {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll('a[evtid="expand_collapse"]');
  if (idx < a.length) {
    if (a[idx].parentNode.getAttribute("_expand") !== "collapse") fireEventClick(a[idx]);
    ExpandEvents(++idx);
  }
}
ExpandEvents(0)
```

Comment: Tried everything else, and this is what ended up working for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609717/calendar-expand-all-by-default

Kind Regards, 
JP

Comment: Thanks JP for the reply.
But when i tested those scripts i can't get to see the calendar Tools in the ribbon anymore